# Symfony 5 custom route with param result in 404 error

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony5

I'm new to Symfony 5 (I started learning it today) and I'm following a course on symfonycasts.com about it, I've done everything as the teacher showed but I still got a 404 error on my controller redirection, here's the code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class QuestionController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function homepage()
    {
        return new Response('Homepage');
    }

    /**
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/q/{$param}")
     */
    public function showQuestions($param)
    {
        return new Response(sprintf("Hello %s!", $param));
    }
}
```

As you see it's a real simple code, but when I go to http://localhost I have the 'Homepage', if I change the

```php
    /**
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/q/{$param}")
     */
    public function showQuestions($param)
    {
        return new Response(sprintf("Hello %s!", $param));
    }
```

to

```php
    /**
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/q")
     */
    public function showQuestions()
    {
        return new Response("Hello World");
    }
```

I have "Hello World" on http://localhost/q
But when I add the /{param} to my annotation like http://localhost/q/Jean I have the Error page telling me that http://localhost/q/Jean does not exist.
I have a .htaccess file in my public folder generated by

```sh
composer req symfony:apache-pack
```

and I also tried to clean the php cache and change the development mod with

```sh
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

but I still have the error.
I'm running my symfony app on a XAMPP server Version: XAMPP for Linux 7.4.1-1
On ubuntu 18.04 and Apache 2.4.29

Comment: would you link the tutorial you're following? also, I doubt that the dollar sign is part of the place holder, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are using {$param} instead of {param} at your @Route.
See [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-parameters).

Comment: well this is how stupid I am, thank you this solves the problem